# How to select only particular word start with # from sentence mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

let's explain briefly

this is very new topic, I want to fetch only particular word start with # from sentence for example

i have sentence like

Hi Majjx Uxud Xhhxhd Hx Dhx  #hdhd Jdhhdhshhfd Hxhhd @bhd Hxhd Hxhhd Dhhdh www.myinnos.in Hdhd Xfhhxhd Xhhdh Xhx 9560233669 ndhdh Hxhhdh Dhh

from above sentence I have to fetch #hdhd

got a solution for my question, now I want to count and show the repeated words as count

```
select val from(
select (substring_index(substring_index(a, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1)) val
from (select id, message as a from filmbooknewsfeed) t
cross join(
 select a.n + b.n * 10 + 1 n
 from 
    (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
        select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
    ) a,
    (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
        select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
    ) b
    order by n
) n
where n.n <= 1 + (length(t.a) - length(replace(t.a, ' ', '')))
order by val asc
)x where val like '#%'
```

Comment: Hint : First, you need to split the sentence and convert into rows. Btw, your statement `I am waiting for your sql query` make your question like a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, you need to convert the sentence into rows. Just in case, if in sentence you have more than 1 words start with `#`.

```
select val from(
select (substring_index(substring_index(a, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1)) val
from (
    select 'Hi Majjx Uxud Xhhxhd Hx Dhx #hdhd Jdhhdhshhfd Hxhhd @bhd Hxhd Hxhhd Dhhdh www.myinnos.in Hdhd Xfhhxhd Xhhdh Xhx 9560233669 ndhdh Hxhhdh Dhh' as a
) t 
cross join(
 select a.n + b.n * 10 + 1 n
 from 
    (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
        select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
    ) a,
    (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
        select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
    ) b
    order by n
) n
where n.n <= 1 + (length(t.a) - length(replace(t.a, ' ', '')))
order by val asc
)x where val like '#%'
```

Will give you `#hdhd`. even if you has more than 1 `#` in the sentence. This would give you correct result.

*edit*
If you want to group by result and sort by most occurence words like twitter tranding topic, modify your query like this (as query on the question)

```
select val,count(val) as cnt from(
    select (substring_index(substring_index(a, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1)) val
    from (select id, message as a from filmbooknewsfeed) t
    cross join(
     select a.n + b.n * 10 + 1 n
     from 
            (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
                    select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
            ) a,
            (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
                    select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
            ) b
            order by n
    ) n
    where n.n <= 1 + (length(t.a) - length(replace(t.a, ' ', '')))
    order by val asc
)x where val like '#%' 
group by val 
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: @prabhakarthota Actually, This query already tested and it works. Even if you just copy it and paste in your query editor.

Comment: could you please explain the above query? no need brief explanation, for example what is t,n,a

Comment: ya its working if i copy paste but i need to pass attribute and table name, i didnt get where i have to pass ?? attribute name is "message" and table name is testone

Comment: @prabhakarthota If so, then just modify the `t` part to `from (select message as a from testone) t `.

Comment: yup cool !! its working still i have one more doubt if you can please help me !!

Comment: @prabhakarthota Feel free to ask.

Comment: i want to show in order, which is repeated more times that word should come top of the results

Comment: @prabhakarthota Well, Please edit your question. Provide your table structure, sample data and desired result in question. Make sure you post a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for example #test repeated two times, i want to show this in top position, like twitter trending

Comment: @prabhakarthota Put count() and Group By in query.

Comment: am new to sql queries , i got your point but am not getting where i have to put, please can you provide code ?

Comment: @prabhakarthota Please provide your current sql query in question.

Comment: val cnt
#test 3
#hdhd 2
#test 1
#ohzhshx 1

Comment: its printing like this repeating #test two times

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(sentence, '#', 2), '#', -1), ' ', 1)
```

Comment: Need one more `substring_index()`.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: please if you know help me out of this

Comment: There was a typo at the end.

Comment: @prabhakarthota . . . This version is so much easier than the accepted version.

Comment: Even with the current version?